# Module to use jest as chai expect style?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, chai

I am new to `jest`, and I am using `chai` + `mocha` at before. I like to use `chai`'s `expect` style. **Is there any nodejs module which allows me to write `jest` like chai style?**

Instead `expect(isOPDSAgent(ua)).toBeTruthy();` I would like to have `expect(isOPDSAgent(ua)).to.be.ok;` which will make it easy to switch old unit tests.

I tried searching, but can't find it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable by shortening the tile, correcting spelling mistakes, and a bit of language polishing. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

jest supports [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) and you should be able to

**`package.json`**

```
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": // ...
    "chai": // ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/setupChai.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

**`setupChai.js`**

```
// this should overwrite the global expect provided by jest
global.expect = require('chai').expect
```

Comment: im not mean use chai, just stynx follow chai